# List overflowing flex container but not scrolling

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am making an interactive list. The problem I have run into is that when the number of items exceeds the height of the window, the list should be able to be scrolled up/down to view content.

For my list, I am using a flex box so that I can have multiple columns of items as necessary. Also, the window height and width is scaled to fill the screen. (I set fixed dimensions in this test code, however.)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add new item..."></input>
        </div>

        <div class="list-container">
            <ul>
                <li>Entry 1</li>
                <li>Entry 2</li>
                <li>Entry 3</li>
                <li>Entry 4</li>
                <li>Entry 5</li>
                <li>Entry 6</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (.scss)

```
.container {
    margin: auto;
    height: 300px; //**NOTE: This is an arbitrary value for showcase. It really would just scale to the screen size.
    width: 780px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.list {
    .input {
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;

        input {
            color: white;
            background: transparent;
            border: none;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 28px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;

            &:focus {
                outline: 0;
            }
        }

        input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            color: white;
            opacity: 0.6;
            font-style: italic;
        }
    }

    .list-container {
        overflow-y: scroll; //**Doesn't work

        ul {
            margin: 0;
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;

            li {
                flex: 1 0 100%;
                background: #34495e;
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px black;
                color: white;
                list-style: none;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 10px 0px;
                white-space: nowrap;
                font-size: 22px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Full pen is here.](https://codepen.io/chasek/pen/owLjyr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `list` a flex container

```
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to set the `height` of every `div`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%; 
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.list {
  height: 100%;
}
.list .input {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.list .input input {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.list .input input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.list .input input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-style: italic;
}
.list .list-container {
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.list .list-container ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  display: relative;
}
.list .list-container ul li {
  background: #34495e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px black;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add new item..."></input>
        </div>

        <div class="list-container">
            <ul>
                <li>Entry 1</li>
                <li>Entry 2</li>
                <li>Entry 3</li>
                <li>Entry 4</li>
                <li>Entry 5</li>
                <li>Entry 6</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following properties to your `.container`:

```
max-height: 100vh;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: I've been able to get the entire parent container to scroll. Is it possible to get just the list content to scroll (i.e. keep the input bar at the top)? Giving it a height attribute seems to do the trick, but is there a way around that?